# How do friend definitions work? Do they require a namespace-level declaration for accessibility?

Tags: c++, overloading, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

Consider this example:

```
#include <type_traits>

class C { };

struct S {
  friend std::true_type f(C&) {
    return std::true_type();
  }
};
std::false_type f(C&);

int main() { C c; return decltype(f(c))::value; }
```

If I compile it, I get:

```
<source>:10:17: error: functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded
```

However, if I comment out `std::false_type f(C&);`, I get:

```
<source>:12:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'f'
```

How does this make sense? If the `f` inside `S` is undeclared, how can it possibly participate in overload resolution with the `f` outside it?! Conversely, if it's declared, then why can't I access it without declaring an `f` outside it? Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: atl??? Did you want to include adl?

Comment: In the second case, `struct S` has a *hidden friend* `f`.

Comment: @Enlico: Whoops, thanks!!

Comment: @Eljay: If it's hidden how does it participate in overload resolution though?

Comment: Normally a hidden friend participates through ADL.  But the way the friend function is specified, since ADL won't find it, it is inaccessible.

Comment: @Eljay: It just seems so strange to me. Does this imply I need to know (and declare it outside) the signature (and in particular, return type) of a hidden `friend` before I can use it?

Comment: "Does this imply" yes it does, pretty much. What's the problem with it?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: It just feels bizarre. I can't think of any other scenario where I can directly provide a *definition* for something, but the definition is inadequate for using it without a declaration. Usually it's the other way around!

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Btw, I just realized that's not even true. Apparently you can declare the namespace-level function as returning `auto`, and it works as long as you define the hidden friend as returning `auto` too?! But if the hidden one is not declared `auto` then the ns-level one cannot be `auto` either?! It doesn't make sense!

Comment: It's a compromise. Pre-historic C++ injected the friends proper. This made things untenable when templates were involved. The compromise is to support https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Interesting, that provides some context. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Friend functions which are defined at their friend declarations do not introduce names which are visible with ordinary lookup into the enclosing namespace although they have namespace scope, meaning that a matching declaration needs to be provided at namespace scope in order to allow friend functions to be found.

```cpp
struct S {
    friend std::true_type f(C&) {
        return std::true_type();
    }
};
std::true_type f(C&);

int main() { C c; return decltype(f(c))::value; } // valid
```

Please note also that it is possible according to the specification to access these functions using ADL lookup and more specifically under the rules for associated classes.
Thus

```cpp
class C {};

struct S {
    friend std::true_type f(S) {
        return std::true_type();
    }

    friend std::true_type g(C) {
        return std::true_type();
    }
};

int main() { 
    S s; 
    int a = decltype(f(s))::value; // valid

    C c;
    int b = decltype(g(c))::value; // invalid
}
```

Comment: This statement "friend declarations do not introduce names into the enclosing namespace" is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry I meant names which are not visible during ordinary lookup.

Answer (score 1):

For starters these declarations of the function `f`

```
struct S {
  friend std::true_type f(C&) {
    return std::true_type();
  }
};
std::false_type f(C&);
```

conflict with each other because they have different return types.

That is the declaration of the function inside the class introduces the name in the global namespace but makes it invisible in the global namespace until the function will be declared explicitly in the global namespace.

If to remove the second declaration then the function `f` will not be visible in the global namespace because it is declared within the class S. There is no reason for the compiler to search the function name within the definition of the class S.

What you need is to rewrite correctly the second function declaration in the global namespace to make the function visible.

```
struct S {
  friend std::true_type f(C&) {
    return std::true_type();
  }
};
std::true_type f(C&);
```

As for the question in a comment

> Do you know why putting auto is insufficient for the return type of
> the outer f? And why it becomes sufficient if I declare the inner one
> as returning auto as well?

then (the C++ 20 Standard, 9.2.8.5 Placeholder type specifiers)

> 13 Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function
> template with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type
> shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type. Similarly,
> redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template
> with a declared return type that does not use a placeholder type shall
> not use a placeholder.

Comment: Do you know why putting `auto` is insufficient for the return type of the outer `f`? And why it becomes sufficient if I declare the inner one as returning `auto` as well?

Comment: @user541686 The Standard requires that return type specifier to be the same.

Comment: So bizarre... seems like the standard has no logic behind these here. But thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

I think the crux is here (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> **A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class** or class template X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but **is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided** - see namespaces for details.

Now let's observe that the `f` in

```cpp
struct S {
  friend std::true_type f(C&) { // declaration and definition
    return std::true_type();
  }
};
```

and the `f` in

```cpp
std::false_type f(C&); // declaration
```

differ in the return type, so the latter is not a re-declaration of the former or, to use the wording from cppreference, the latter is not *a matching declaration at the namespace scope*.

So, on the one hand, the `friend` `f` it is not visible, *except argument-dependent lookup that considers* our class `S`; but this is not possible, because the `friend` `f` doesn't take any argument "associated with" the class which `f` is `friend` of, namely `S`.

On the other hand, what are the two `f`s to each other? They have the same name `f`, so they are two overloads. But two overloads can't differ just by the return type (in C++ you can ignore the return value of a function, so how could the compiler rely on the type of the returned value?), and that's what the error message tells you.

At the moment you comment out the latter declaration, then no overload exists anymore, but at the same time the `friend` `f` is not visible for what I explained above.